# Update State in a Class Component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
private readonly maxSizeOfDownloadedFiles: number = 1000000;

state = {
  totalSum: this.maxSizeOfDownloadedFiles
};

handleCallback = () => {
  this.setState({ totalSum: 12 })
  alert('totalSum ' + this.state.totalSum);
};
```

When I run handleCallback method it doesn't update totalSum and gives me the default value, alert show **totalSum 1000000** not 12. So why setState doesn't work?

Comment: `setState` doesn't immediately set the state. State updates are async, may be batched, etc.

Comment: `this.setState({...}, () => { // HERE  the value is updated // })`. If you need to use the updated value just after setting it, you can pass a callback as second parameter to check your updated value!  (It is called only after the state is updated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the callback method in `setState({} ,() => {})` which gets called immediately after the state update.

```js
private readonly maxSizeOfDownloadedFiles: number = 1000000;

state = {
  totalSum:  this.maxSizeOfDownloadedFiles
}

handleCallback = () => {
  this.setState({ totalSum: 12}, () => {
   alert('totalSum ' + this.state.totalSum);
 })
}
```